# Rational Exponents

Tags: proof-verification, exponential-function, rational-functions

I'm just checking to see if have the correct answer because my teacher didn't give us an answer key and i like to know that I  have done one question properly before doing the rest.

Evaluate. Express answer as an exact number - No decimals.

$$(3^{\frac 13} \times 5^{-\frac 12})^{6}$$

Here is my work:

$$(3^{\frac 13} \times 5^{-\frac 12})^{6}$$
$$=3^{2} \times 5^{-3}$$
$$=\frac{9\times 1}{125}$$
$$=\frac{9}{125}$$

Now I'm not sure if this is the right answer. For some reason I feel it's wrong.

Comment: You, indeed, have the right solution and your work/method is correct. As a future note, this stack exchange isn't really the right place for these type of questions. Hopefully, an answer will come along soon (but I don't see how it would differ)

Comment: You showed your work, so the question is fine. (And the answer is correct.)

Comment: Actually, these questions are welcomed. Because the answers would be breif, people usually answer in the comments if it is correct, but as a full answer when the work is wrong. It is best to tag these with (proof-verification).

Comment: @MathNoob I'll remember that for next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I admit: I have always wanted to do this.